# How to hide empty fields with custom control?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Fields, that have not any configured control:

```
<field-visibility>
    <show id="foo:bar"/>
</field-visibility>
<appearance>
    <field id="foo:bar" read-only="true" />
</appearance>
```

is only displayed when they have value, even in edit-mode, as of they are *read-only*.

However, when I tried to add a custom control to the field, it is always displayed and readonly doesn't work:

```
<field-visibility>
    <show id="foo:bar"/>
</field-visibility>
<appearance>
    <field id="foo:bar" read-only="true">
        <control template="/com/myCompany/myTemplate">
            <control-param name="myParam">value</control-param>
        </control>
    </field>
</appearance>
```

How to configure the field to be only displayed if thre is a value in it?

Comment: Please show your myTemplate.ftl file. And you need add .ftl extension to contorol-template tag value

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the hidden.ftl as an appearance template:
**org\alfresco\components\form\controls\hidden.ftl**

And the textfield: **org\alfresco\components\form\controls\textfield.ftl**

In the textfield.ftl you'll see the following:

```
<span class="viewmode-label">${field.label?html}:</span>
......
<#if fieldValue == "">${msg("form.control.novalue")}<#else>${fieldValue}</#if></span>
```

On the label side surround it with an **<#if fieldValue == "">** and remove the the following code resided in the if fieldValue **${msg("form.control.novalue")}**